# Track changes in table using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some problems with knockout js. I'm trying to make page for comments moderation.
In web service I get all comments and convert them to JSON.
The result JSON looks like this:

```
{"Comments":[{"Title":"Title-01","Body":"Body-01","Id":41,"IsDeleted":false},
{"Title":"Title-02","Body":"Body-02","Id":41,"IsDeleted":true},
{"Title":"Title-03","Body":"Body-03","Id":41,"IsDeleted":true},
{"Title":"Title-04","Body":"Body-04","Id":41,"IsDeleted":false},
...
]}
```

My view model is:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var moderationViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            this.Comments = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
            this.GetComments = function () {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Web service url",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (data) {
                    self.SuccessfullyRetrievedCommentsFromService(data);
                  }
                });
             };

             this.SuccessfullyRetrievedCommentsFromService = function (result) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Comments, self.Comments);
             };
       };

       var moderationCommentsViewModel = new moderationViewModel();
       moderationCommentsViewModel.GetComments();
       ko.applyBindings(moderationCommentsViewModel);  
});
```

And the markup of table is:

```
<table class="actable">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="575px" />
    <col width="25px" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: Comments -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5><q data-bind="text: Title() + ' (' + Id() + ')'"></q></h5>
        <p data-bind="text: Body"></p>
      </td>
      <td class="tcenter">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsDeleted">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On the server side I have a database that stores info about comments. Editor may check comment as deleted and this comment will not show for the visitors of the side.
I want somehow to track rows in the html table that were changed (checked/unchecked) and pass these to the web service. If comments' checkbox were checked/unchecked I have to change info about it status int the database' table. 
I do not want to iterate over through the whole Comments array to find which items were checked/unchecked before sending to server because table can contain thousands rows and I think it will be performance hit.
Is there right way to find out which rows were changed using knockoit? My thoughts were to create separate array and add/delete items to it when checkbox value was changed. But I do not know how to handle click on the checbox right way. Is it possible?

Comment: I solved my problem using manual aubscription.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 3):

I added a change tracking utility for Knockout to NuGet and on codeplex. You can grab it from one of these links. http://kochangetracker.codeplex.com/ or https://nuget.org/packages/Knockout.ChangeTracker

Answer (score 1):

I've have reproduced code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AlfeG/vMU7z/3/ (excluding ajax part)

And it's seems to me that the only error You have is in line with mapping:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Comments, self.Comments);
```

Second parameter for mapping plugin is [mapping configuration](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#specifying_the_update_target). So the correct use would be:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Comments, {}, self.Comments);
```

Also `self.Comments` can be specified as `ko.observableArray()`

> > But I do not know how to handle click on the checbox right way. Is it possible?

As You can see on the demo that I've provided KnockoutJS is tracing all changes to checkbox. So You can easily access data via viewModel object.

Comment: Mapping in my model works correct. You can check this link http://jsfiddle.net/vMU7z/4/. But it does not matter. I have missed some details for the sake to decrease post' length. The essence of the question is how to track only changed rows, pass them to the server and do not affect performance.